# Does upgrading Ubuntu install again the packages I uninstalled?

Tags: upgrade

I installed 20.10 a few months ago and since then uninstalled using apt some packages I do not need on my system, like the cups subsystem –as I don't have a printer– and all the snaps plus the snap daemon –as I prefer to use apt and .deb packages.

I also uninstalled the package *update-manager-core*, which I suspect might be needed for the upgrade process.

As this is my first go at Ubuntu and I have never upgraded the system before, I wonder if the packages I uninstalled (using apt) will remain uninstalled after upgrade.

I know the upgrade doesn't overwrites the modified system files, but it's not clear to me if it will leave my system as it is and just upgrade what is installed.

**Edit:** Thanks for the helpful answers, as I want the release-upgrade to be as smooth as possible, I decided do reinstall most of the packages and disable what I don't need using systemctl or the configuration files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's get the terms straight so there is no misunderstanding.

- An *upgrade* occurs frequently (daily/weekly) and keeps you on the **same** release of Ubuntu.
- A *release-upgrade* occurs every 6 months (or 2 years for LTS) and migrates you to a **newer** release of Ubuntu.
- A *dist-upgrade* is a Debian term for migrating to a newer release of Debian. It's a slightly different method, and you might see references to it in the documentation. We do not test dist-upgrades, nor recommend their use in Ubuntu.

---

Okay, now to answer your question:

A daily/weekly **upgrade** will replace only packages that you already have installed. It won't install new packages. (However, you likely intended to ask about a release-upgrade instead)

A 6-month/2-year **release-upgrade** does require the `update-manager-core` package. It also will indeed install some new packages, and will orphan some obsolete packages. A release-upgrade generally won't reinstall packages that you have uninstalled (unless something on your system needs them).

---

**Advice:** Release-upgrades can sometimes go wrong on highly-customized systems. If you have made a lot of changes, you can improve the likelihood of a clean, error-free release-upgrade by restoring your system to as close to stock condition as possible.

That means uninstalling your customizations and re-installing the `update-manager-core` and `ubuntu-desktop` packages. Backing up your data is wise, too. After the successful release-upgrade, you can restore your customizations.

Answer (score 0):

The command explains all :

`sudo apt upgrade`

From the `apt-get` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get)

> Upgrade:
> Used to install the newest versions of all packages currently installed on the system [...] Packages currently installed with new versions available are retrieved and upgraded; under no circumstances are currently installed packages removed, nor are packages that are not already installed retrieved and installed. New versions of currently installed packages that cannot be upgraded without changing the install status of another package will be left at their current version. An update must be performed first so that apt-get knows that new versions of packages are available.

This mean that, like on every OS, if you have uninstalled an app, that you installed, it will not be reinstalled (except if an app that you upgrade has this app in dependency)